# Inserting in a max heap

Tags: java, heap

I could use a little help. So heapsize is declared as the number of elements in the array. data is the array. Why do we do heapsize++? maxSize is also declared as the size of the array. Lets say we add the element to the heap, it goes in the last position. Why increase heapsize first and not just put it in data[heapsize] since heapsize will be the last empty position. Thanks!

```
public void insert(int item) 
{
    int position;
    if (isFull()) throw new Exception();
    heapsize++;
    data[heapsize-1] = item;
    position = heapsize - 1;
    while (position>0 && data[(position-1)/2])
    {
        swap(position, (position-1/2));
        position = (position-1)/2;
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be `if(data[(position-1)/2] < data[position]) `

Comment: Confusing and buggy code. Can't you get rid of it and code by your own? I wish you could.

Comment: When you increment `heapsize` is a matter of style. Before or after inserting makes no difference. Your bigger problem is that the conditional in your `while` statement is broken. You need to be comparing the item at `position` with its parent. What you have written will always move the item to the root, unless the item you insert is 0.

Answer (score 0):

`maxSize` is the maximum capacity of your heap, whereas `heapsize` keeps tracks of the number of elements currently in the heap, which can be less or equal to `maxSize`.So everytime an item is inserted in the heap, the `heapsize` is increased by `1`.

You can also increase the `heapsize` after the insertion then you have to write

`data[heapsize] = item;` instead of `data[heapsize-1] = item;`.